# Sumifs function in Python on a list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do what would be a simple sumif function in Excel. 
My dataframe looks like this:

```
Value|CatA|CatB|CatC
0.88 | 1  | 1  | 1
0.25 | 1  | 1  | 4
0.54 | 4  | 2  | 3
0.15 | 3  | 2  | 2
0.14 | 1  | 3  | 2
```

I wanted the summation of Value for each category, from number 1-4:

So:

```
Number CatA   CatB CatC
1      |1.27 |1.13|0.88
2      | 0   |0.69|0.29
3      |0.15 |0.14|0.54
4      |0.54 |0   |0.25
```

Have tried numerous things like groupby etc, but can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the conditions. How do you get 0s ?

Comment: [Excel's SUMIFS implemented using PANDAS](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42695/excels-sumifs-implemented-using-pandas-the-python-data-analysis-library)

Comment: @CeliusStingher I think it's because CatA as 0 2's

Comment: Oh, I just got it, but this is not a `sumif` operation but rather a pivoting one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and then [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df.melt(id_vars='Value').pivot_table(index='value', 
                                     columns='variable', 
                                     values='Value', 
                                     aggfunc='sum', 
                                     fill_value=0)

variable  CatA  CatB  CatC
value                     
1         1.27  1.13  0.88
2         0.00  0.69  0.29
3         0.15  0.14  0.54
4         0.54  0.00  0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use [`groupby.sum`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) + [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) after `melt`

```
new_df = ( df.melt('Value')
             .groupby(['value','variable'])['Value']
             .sum()
             .unstack(fill_value = 0)
             .rename_axis(columns = None,
                          index = 'Number')
             .reset_index())
print(new_df)
   Number  CatA  CatB  CatC
0       1  1.27  1.13  0.88
1       2  0.00  0.69  0.29
2       3  0.15  0.14  0.54
3       4  0.54  0.00  0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

another method using `pd.crosstab`

```
s = df.melt('Value',value_name='Number')
new_df = pd.crosstab(s.Number, s.variable, s.Value, aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
new_df.columns.name =''
```

---

```
print(new_df)
        CatA  CatB  CatC
Number                  
1       1.27  1.13  0.88
2       0.00  0.69  0.29
3       0.15  0.14  0.54
4       0.54  0.00  0.25
```